# facebook app development shared account

Tags: facebook, shared, account, facebook-group

As a web development business we want to create facebook apps for our clients and retain access to them through some for of shared account.

Facebook terms clearly state that you can't set up fake accounts.

Is there any legal way that you can create applications that are shared amongst a group of developers? groups can't create apps, business accounts can't create apps.

What has been your solution to this problem? We can't risk FB shutting down a shared Dev account just because its not a real person.